# flexbox: distribute elements vertically in Safari

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to distribute three items in the mobile portrait view. Used `flex` and it works in all others browsers except safari. so it is not working in iphone.

I have used `align-content: space-between;` and `flex-flow: row wrap;` together to get the alignment. What are the correct properties to be used to make it work in Safari?

[-> Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/fby1tno4/)

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap{
  display: -webkit-box;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;-webkit-box-direction: normal;-ms-flex-direction: column;flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: justify;align-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
   flex-flow: row wrap;

}
div[class*="col"]{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col1">

  </div>
  <div class="col1">

  </div>
  <div class="col1">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is missing the necessary `-webkit-` prefixes for older Safari versions:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;

-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;

-webkit-align-content: space-between;
align-content: space-between;

-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

References:

- http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html
- http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox (click "Show all")
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: Yeah, I did check. But for me your original code is stacking vertically in Safari. Maybe you're on a previous version, which is why I posted `-webkit-` prefixes.

Comment: not only about stacking, need to distribute vertically. so third box is at bottom.

Comment: Yes. In my iPad & iPhone it's all working fine, like in Chrome and FF.